# Evaluate Expression with Powers

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

1. I am having difficulties trying to figure out these two questions from the book. First one says to write a program to evaluate:

3x^3 - 5x^2 + 6

x = 2.55

What i wrote was:

```
double x, result;
    x = 2.55;
    result = 3*x*3 - 5*x*2 + 6;
    NSLog(@"The answer is %.3f", result);
```

Output: The answer is 3.450
i don't know if this is correct or not.

2. Next question is write program to evaluate and display results. (remember to use exponential format to display) -- What is the exponential format I am supposed to use?

(3.31 x 10^-8 + 2.01 x 10^-7) / (7.16 x 10^-6 + 2.01 x 10^-8)

How do I display the -8, -7 and how to display the powers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `#include <math.h>` at the top of your code and then you can use Objective-C's `pow()` function like so:

x^3 + 6: `pow(x, 3) + 6`

10^-8 + 2: `pow(10, -8)+ 2`

Comment: Just going to nitpick a little here. `pow()` is a C function, and there's no need for OP to include `math.h`, since they're using `NSLog()`, implying that they've already directly or indirectly imported Foundation, which imports `CoreFoundation.h`, which includes `math.h`.